# How to deserialize Date ISO String to DateTime Object in built_value serialization in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, built-value

I wanna serialize a json object including an `ISOString` date to a dart object using built value.

this is a sample json:

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "description": "test description",
  "date": "2020-06-05T11:42:38.585Z",
  "creator": {
    "email": "test@test.com"
  }
}
```

this is the model:

```
abstract class Post implements Built<Post, PostBuilder> {
  @nullable
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: '_id')
  String get id;

  String get title;

  String get description;

  DateTime get date;

  @nullable
  User get creator;

  Post._();

  static Serializer<Post> get serializer => _$postSerializer;

  factory Post([updates(PostBuilder b)]) = _$Post;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      serializers.deserializeWith(Post.serializer, map);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      serializers.serializeWith(Post.serializer, this);
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Deserializing '[title, test1, description, test1 description, date, 2020-06-05T...' to  
'Post' failed due to: Deserializing '2020-06-05T11:42:38.585Z' to 'DateTime' failed due  
to: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast
```

how do I fix that?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to know if you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom `DateTime` serializer that you can find here: [Iso8601DateTimeSerializer](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/built_value/lib/iso_8601_date_time_serializer.dart)

1. create a new dart file (I named it *iso8601_date_time_serializer.dart*)
2. paste the code from [1](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/built_value/lib/iso_8601_date_time_serializer.dart)
3. add the import to your *serializers.dart* file (import 'iso8601_date_time_serializer.dart';)
4. edit your *serializers.**g**.dart* file

```
Serializers _$serializers = (new Serializers().toBuilder()

  ..add(Iso8601DateTimeSerializer())

  ..add(Post.serializer) // I assume you have this in yours

  ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin()))

.build();
```

Please note that this modification might be deleted if you regenerate the code with `build_runner`.

In case you want to dig deeper, I got the answer from [built_value GitHub issue 454](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/454)

Comment: You shouldn't modify your `serializers.g.dart` file - you can put the config in your `serializers.dart` file directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the `Iso8601DateTimeSerializer` directly from `built_value` - don't copy the file over to your project.

Your final `serializers.dart` should look like:

```
import 'package:built_value/iso_8601_date_time_serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/iso_8601_duration_serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';

part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor([
  // your built value classes
])
final Serializers serializers = (_$serializers.toBuilder()
  ..add(Iso8601DateTimeSerializer())
  ..add(Iso8601DurationSerializer())
  ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
).build();
```